# Is the integral result of $\int \frac{e^{-kr}+e^{-i\vec{q}\vec{r}}}{r} d^3r$ from contour integration?

Tags: integration

I know that $\int \frac{e^{-kr}+e^{-i\vec{q}\vec{r}}}{r}  d^3r = \frac{4\pi}{q^2+k^2}$. But I wonder how to get the result. The term $q^2+k^2$ seem to come from contour integration with poles. But how to carry it out explicitly and is there alternative method to compute this integral. I also wonder where does the $4\pi$ come from.

$d^3r$ is a volume integral with ($r = |r|$) between the distance.

Comment: the second part of this integral diverges... use polar coordinates to see this

Comment: Contour integration does not apply in 3D. $4\pi$ is the full-space solid angle.

Comment: What's the integration domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is certainly wrong, as the value must be of the form

$$f(k)+g(\vec q).$$

---

Now assuming a product instead of a sum, and assuming integration on the whole space, you can rotate the coordinates to make $\vec q$ parallel to $z$ and

$$I=\iiint\frac{e^{-kr}e^{-iqz}}rdxdydz=\iiint\frac{e^{-kr}e^{-iqr\cos\phi}}rr^2\sin\phi\, drd\theta d\phi.$$

We have $$\int e^{-iqr\cos\phi}\sin\phi\,d\phi=\left.\frac1{iqr}e^{-iqr\cos\phi}\right|_0^\pi=\frac{2\sin(qr)}{qr}$$

Then after integration on $\theta$,

$$I=\frac{4\pi}q\int_0^\infty \sin(qr)e^{-kr}dr.$$

Comment: yes it's a product. I do not know how to evaluate your latest integral to get to my results. Can you show me also? Thanks.

Comment: @peter: sorry no. It's time for you to spend a little effort.

Comment: do i need contour integral?

Comment: @peter You can probably do it with a contour integral, but there is simpler.

Comment: simple? can you me some tips?

Comment: @peter: web search.